# Error while running app in Emulator (Genymotion)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

1. i cant run my app in android emulator (genymotion), when i run my app in genymotion it was force close and show me this message : "Unfortunately, komber3 has stopped" error is there in code "***getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);***" 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz1dn.jpg)

Comment: please add the complete exception log

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize you actionbar with Toolbar

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);    
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I think you got NullPointerException error which means you don`t have instance of your actionbar.I hope this will help you